# Make a difference. First you rise, then you fall

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> With me you can make a difference.
>
> With me reversed, I'll rise and I'll fall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are the word:

> **EDIT** - when you 'edit' something (for instance, a post on a StackExchange site, like this one) you quite literally *make a difference* by altering some of its content.

Reversed, this then gives you:

> **TIDE** - the level of the sea *rises and falls* every day, as a result of the [tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide), influenced by the pull of the moon, giving us high and low tides.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a stretch, but i think you are

> Minus

With me you can make a difference.

> Is you want to know the difference between two numbers, you will subtract them with a MINUS sign

With me reversed, I'll rise and I'll fall.

> The SUN does raise and fall daily and in reverse you clearly tell us "SUN I (a)M"